# Alternative to Aggregate Case Statements SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created a view that does aggregation based on CASE expressions. The transaction tables the view is based on has approximately 900 million rows.  I need to aggregate values based on multiple criteria including dates and product codes.  I will need to do a full scan of the data at least once as we do some aggregation without filters so I figured using case statements would allow it to do just 1 scan instead of having to run a query for each criterion.

What I'm finding is that having so many aggregated case statements really slows things down.

Here is an example of my Query with only 2 columns (in the real query there would be probably 50 columns)

```
SELECT  [ContactID] AS [ContactID],
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
                           WHEN [Category] = 'Dog Food'
                                AND [TransactionDate]
                                BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                                THEN [TransactionDate]
                           ELSE NULL
                       END
            )       AS [Dog_FoodTx12mth],
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
                           WHEN [Category] = 'Cat Food'
                                AND [Lifestage] LIKE 'Kitten%'
                                AND [TransactionDate]
                                BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -3, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                                THEN [TransactionDate]
                           ELSE NULL
                       END
            )       AS [Cat_FoodKittenTx3mth]
FROM    [dbo].[GI_TransactionLineProductContact]
GROUP BY [ContactID];
```

Edit question for clarity:

Is there another method than aggregating CASE expressions that would potentially be more efficient keeping in mind I'm going to have to do a full read of the table at least once anyway? I think my main problem is all the nested loops for the different CASE expressions, each new case expression seems to add quite a bit of cost.  If I do an estimated execution plan for a query on the same criteria with 2 CASE expressions and one with 50 CASE expressions the first query shows a 20% cost and the second shows a 80% batch cost.

So I think maybe this design isn't the most efficient and I'm looking for potential alternative methods I could use.

Thanks

Comment: Can you get rid of the `count(distinct)`?

Comment: also, can't you replace `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` with `GETDATE()`? Not sure what you're trying to do with that? or do: `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: No can't get rid of the distinct in this case.  The dateadd is stripping the time from the date.  Yes I could do cast(GetDate() as Date) however my research has shown that the dateadd method is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your query is wrong.
It will give the wrong output

Secondly use DISTINCT is not clear.

Try my script,if you are not getting right output then you can put back DISTINCT

```
SELECT  [ContactID] AS [ContactID],
        sum( CASE
                           WHEN [Category] = 'Dog Food'
                                AND [TransactionDate]
                                BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                                THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                       END
            )       AS [Dog_FoodTx12mth],
        SUM(CASE
                           WHEN [Category] = 'Cat Food'
                                AND [Lifestage] LIKE 'Kitten%'
                                AND [TransactionDate]
                                BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -3, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                                THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                       END
            )       AS [Cat_FoodKittenTx3mth]
FROM    [dbo].[GI_TransactionLineProductContact]
GROUP BY [ContactID];
```

Why your query might be wrong ?

```
select count(*) from
(
select 1 col
union all
select null
)t4
```

Output return is 2.desire output=1.Am I wrong/correct ?

In case you hv to use DISTINCT then using CTE filter duplicate record using single distinct or row_number()over(partition by category,transactiondate order by transactiondate)rn

Comment: Can you explain specifically why my output is wrong?

I need distinct because the transaction date is returned multiple times for each product purchased in the transaction.  I only want to count the number of unique number of dates that meet the criteria.  Not each row.  I return nulls where the criteria isn't met as COUNT does not count nulls.

Comment: @Bee_Riii , check my answer.BTW Is my output wrong ?

Comment: Your answer doesn't include the column. 

Try 

select count(ExampleColumn) from
(
select 1 ExampleColumn
union all
select NULL AS ExampleColumn
)t4

Comment: Great @Bee_Riii ,such a silly mistake.This is so important to remember.Thanks.phew how about my output and performance ?

Comment: I can't test your output performance as it's not the same output as mine.  Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

it is more efficient to group by ContactID+Category+Lifestage+interval of TransactionDate you need (eg td_year, td_month, td_day)+ any other field you need as criteria. Then use standard aggregates and finally select that set group by ContactID from an outer select using any technique suits you (WITH, temp tables, nested select, view,...).